# In Ruby, compare an array and hash function and if the key matches the array element return/replace it with the value of the key

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash, compare

Within run I have a hash function called dictionary. 
I am trying to take the hash of key:value pairs and loop them through a string/sentence. 
I convert the string into an array and then I want to loop that array with the replacement_words hash. If the array element is == to the key in the hash then I want to replace it with the value of the key.

```
def dictionary
  replacement_words={
    'hello' => 'hola',
    'two' => 'dos',
    'goodbye' => 'adios',
    'ten' => 'diez',
    '4' => 'cuatro',
    'house' => 'casa',
    'cat' => 'gato'
  }
end
```

Below I need to call on the dictionary hash function and I want to return the string with the replaced words. 'Hello' should be replaced with 'Hola'.

```
def spanglish(sentence)
  array=[]
  main_key=dictionary.to_a
  main_value=dictionary.values
  sentence_array=tweets.split(" ")
  sentence_array.collect do |word|
     if word == "to"
       array << "2"
     else
       array << word
    end 
  end 
  array.join(" ")
  array


end
```

Note: only using ruby programming not ruby on rails.

Sample input:

```
"Hello it has been two days since your cat has visited my house"
```

Output:

```
"Hola it has been dos days since your gato has visited my casa"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map each word in the sentence, and try to access the replacement_words hash for each word, if you can get the value for a specific key, then you're done, if not, then you use the same word:

```
replacement_words = {
  'hello' => 'hola',
  'two' => 'dos',
  'goodbye' => 'adios',
  'ten' => 'diez',
  '4' => 'cuatro',
  'house' => 'casa',
  'cat' => 'gato'
}

sentence = 'Hola it has been dos days since your gato has visited my casa'
p sentence.split.map { |word| replacement_words[word.downcase] || word }.join(' ')
# "hola it has been dos days since your gato has visited my casa"
```

Since Hello isn't in the replacement_words then it won't get the value, but you can downcase the word, which would make the sentence apply the key as it's in the hash.

Comment: Your answer was the easiest solution provided. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple, perhaps?

```
replacement_words = {
  'hello'   => 'hola',
  'two'     => 'dos',
  'goodbye' => 'adios',
  'ten'     => 'diez',
  '4'       => 'cuatro',
  'house'   => 'casa',
  'cat'     => 'gato',
  'lola'    => 'gertrude'
}

str = "Hello it has been two days since Lola has visited my house"

h = dictionary
str.gsub(/\b\p{Alpha}+\b/) do |word|
  downword = word.downcase
  if h.key?(downword)
    downword == word ? h[downword] : h[downword].capitalize
  else
    word
  end
end
  #=> "Hola it has been dos days since Gertrude has visited my casa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **Hello** isn't necessarily the same as **hello**, you'll need to decide if they're the same thing, and either create separate translations for them or tell your hash to treat them the same. You can also tell your hash of translations to return the word being passed in, if it can't find a key with that value by using a [`default_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D):

```
replacement_words = {
  'hello' => 'hola',
  'two' => 'dos',
  'goodbye' => 'adios',
  'ten' => 'diez',
  '4' => 'cuatro',
  'house' => 'casa',
  'cat' => 'gato'
}

# Both 'Hello' and 'hello' come out as 'hola' (both return downcase)
# words not found in the Hash return the value you're checking
replacement_words.default_proc = ->(hash, key) do
  hash.fetch(key.downcase, key)
end
```

and then you can simply run a [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) on your string to match all words in the string and replace it with the value in `replacement_words` hash:

```
sentence = "Hello it has been two days since your cat has visited my house"
sentence.gsub(/\b(\w+)\b/, dictionary)
# => "hola it has been dos days since your gato has visited my casa"
```

`\b` is a word boundary and `\w+` is one or more word characters, so match all word characters between 2 word boundary's.

Since we treated both **Hello** and **hello** (and all variations of uppercase/lowercase letters) the same as **hello**, the resulting **hola** is lowercase. If you know these are going to be sentences, you can just call `capitalize` on it:

```
sentence.gsub(/\b(\w+)\b/, replacement_words).capitalize
# => "Hola it has been dos days since your gato has visited my casa"
```

If you would prefer to handle the variations in upper/lower case on your own you can use a simpler `default_proc`:

```
replacement_words = {
  'Hello' => 'Hola',
  'hello' => 'hola',
  # ... the rest of the hash the same
}

replacement_words.default_proc = ->(_, key) { key }

sentence = "Hello it has been two days since your cat has visited my house"
sentence.gsub(/\b(\w+)\b/, replacement_words)
# => "Hola it has been dos days since your gato has visited my casa"
```

Comment: Yes, hola and Hola would be the same. so 'Hello' => 'Hola'  and 'hello' => 'hola'. Currently not able to test your response, but I will review it in a few hours.

Comment: Note that `replacement_words` is mutated by attaching the proc.

Answer (score 0):

[`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) accepts a hash as replacement:

```
string.gsub(Regexp.union(replacement_words.keys), replacement_words)
```

For this to work, the initial hash should be updated upfront to distinguish capitalized words:

```
replacement_words =
  replacement_words.merge(
    replacement_words.
      reject { |e| e =~ /\A\d/ }.
      map { |h| h.map(&:capitalize) }.
      to_h
    )
```